# Proper way to keep Phonegap-Facebook-Plugin / Facebook JS api user logged in to app?

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the Phonegap-Facebook-Plugin to log people in to a phonegap app, and the app keeps kicking the user out to the login page after some time. What's the proper way to keep a user logged in when the re-open the app? Should I check to see if they're logged in still when their re-open the app, and automatically log them back in if they aren't? Or is there a way to keep them logged in over longer periods of time?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is to rely on the HTML5 local storage. Create a local key/value and stick testing over it.

After logging in:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn','true');
```

In index.html, check your local storage value:

```
if ( window.localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') === 'true'){
    // User is already logged in, he shouldn't be here. Move him from this screen
}
```

After logging out:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn','false');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Do you know if this has more to do with storing the logged in state vs. getting a long-term access token? eg  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens